# detecting player ID - fivem to js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, fivem

**hello iam developing a bot for fivem in javascript language but i dont know how to detect the player id for people who join the server please can any help this is my code**

```
on('playerConnecting', async(name, setKickReason, deferrals) => {
        const chann = client.channels.cache.get("room id")
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("serverid");
    deferrals.defer()
    deferrals.update("message")
    const player = global.source;
    let discord = "**undefined**";
    let steam = "**undefined**";
    let fivem = "**undefined**";
    let ip = "**undefined**";
    let license = "**undefined**";
    for (let i = 0; i < GetNumPlayerIdentifiers(player); i++) {
        const identifier = GetPlayerIdentifier(player, i);
        if (identifier.includes('discord:')) {
            discord = identifier
        } else if(identifier.includes('steam:')) {
            steam = identifier
        } else if(identifier.includes('fivem:')) {
            fivem = identifier
        } else if(identifier.includes("ip:")) {
            ip = identifier;
        }else if(identifier.includes("license:")) {
            license = identifier;
        }
    }
setTimeout(async() => {
    discord = discord.split('discord:').pop()
    steam = steam.split('steam:').pop()
    ip = ip.split('ip:').pop()
    license = license.split('license:').pop()
    fivem = fivem.split('fivem:').pop()
    let pingg = GetPlayerPing(player)
    let embed= new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RED")
            .addField(`**Default Name**`,`**${name}**`)
            .addField(`**Steam Name**`,`**${steam}**`)
            .addField(`**FiveM Name**`,`**${fivem}**`)
            .addField(`**Discord Name**`,`<@${discord}>`)
            .addField(`**Discord id**`,`**${discord}**`)
            .addField(`**IP**`,`**${ip}**`)
            .addField(`**License**`,`**${license}**`)
            .addField(`**Ping**`,`**${pingg}**`)
            .addField(`**player-id**`,`**${player.id}**`)
            .setFooter(guild.name)
            .setTimestamp()
            let mes = await chann.send(embed)
```

**i tried to put [player.id] in the field but didnt work**

Answer (score 0):

Native commands are mapped to global JavaScript functions with names similar to the Lua natives mapping [per FiveM native docs](https://docs.fivem.net/docs/scripting-manual/runtimes/javascript/)

Therefore you should be able to use the native `GetPlayerServerId` like you have used other natives (`GetPlayerPing`, `GetPlayerIdentifier`, etc.)

```
.addField(`**player-id**`,`**${GetPlayerServerId(player)}**`)
```

You can see all the native for JS and Lua in the [documentation](https://docs.fivem.net/natives/?_0x344EA166).